# Seemingly arbitrary slowdown with lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply, ggmap

I'm building a process that uses the `decodeLine` function [here](http://s4rdd.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-maps-api-decoding-polylines-for.html) to translate Encoded Polylines to Lat/Lon pairs. `decodeLine` works flawlessly on individual records, and I can use lapply to get it to chunk through my list (~150) of unique Polylines:

```
links.decoded <- lapply(as.list(links.encoded$EncodedPolyLine), FUN=decodeLine)
```

Here's where things get interesting: the lapply call is hanging on specific Polyline records. An individual decodeLine(X) call is almost instantaneous; calling it on most subsets from `links.encoded` is likewise very fast, but only until the subset contains one of a handful of records. Focusing in on one problematic Polyline value, the issue doesn't look to be related to the actual content of the value: passing it alone as the argument for `decodeLine` is as fast as any other valid call. So, the issue seems to be related to my use of lapply in this context.

Can anyone share insight? I'm sure I can hack a way around the issue, but I'm curious as to what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't use `apply`? The conversion to the list is useless and counterproductive. Please next time post a reproducible example

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear - wasn't sure it was relevant to the core of the question. I'm using lapply because the output of `decodeLine` will be a two-field array of arbitrary length (depends on the number of Lat/Long points that were originally encoded to create the Polyline). Wanted to isolate and split this out. You're right though - the `as.list` is redundant if I'm using `$`.

Comment: No one can help unless you provide a reproducible example. But I will be very surprised if the slowness is from `lapply`, rather than a combination of your particular data and `decodeLine`.

Comment: Have worked on it some more - I think you're right, joran. All of the other EPLs work. Here are two examples, if anyone's interested to give it a shot: "w~mwFjisbMXnEXdCh@bCf@zAd@jA^r@" and 
"cl}wFtbkaMfFiIdByBrD{DtAeAj@_@nA}@|BcAvBy@hBc@zDm@jBOrBY|C_@f@EpHk@|Is@????bIOrGa@xHcBvFyBtImDzHgDtBcAtCoApCgAbEqA~QuHxGqDbCUbCRjEcApEy@jGeAtEi@dBg@t@SdRyGzHwC|IcDbKuDdLeEnM}ExOwFzRsHnCoArGeEtOaQjGqMbCoJ|@{GDuIe@Sf". Second code is the offender; the length doesn't seem to be the issue, as the function works fine with longer values.

Comment: That second example is not a valid encoding - there's something wrong with it. (tested using `googleway::decode_pl()`)